# Remove unwanted states from dropdown list in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, magento

I am new to magento and I am not able to make out how one can remove the unwanted states from dropdown list in magento. I tried to edit my below function as per this link **http://doejo.com/blog/magento-how-to-remove-certain-states-from-state-region-list-at-checkout-or-registration/** but it did not work. Below i sthe code for removing unwanted states but when I add to my class in local folder, not getting any results.

```
    $excludeRegions = array('AE','AA');
            foreach ($collection as $region) {
                if (!$region->getRegionId()) {
                    continue;
                }
                ***//Here is the code from the link given
                 //BOF Custom Logic Here***
                $regionCode = $region->getCode();
                $this->_select->from(array('region'=>$this->_regionTable),
                array('region_id'=>'region_id', 'country_id'=>'country_id', 'code'=>'code', 'default_name'=>'default_name')
                )->where('code NOT IN (?)', $exclude_regions);
```

*`_getRegions` function edited as per above code and link respectively.*

```
protected function _getRegions($storeId)
    {
        $countryIds = array();

        $countryCollection = $this->getCountryCollection()->loadByStore($storeId);
        foreach ($countryCollection as $country) {
            $countryIds[] = $country->getCountryId();
        }

        /** @var $regionModel Mage_Directory_Model_Region */
        $regionModel = $this->_factory->getModel('directory/region');
        /** @var $collection Mage_Directory_Model_Resource_Region_Collection */
        $collection = $regionModel->getResourceCollection()
            ->addCountryFilter($countryIds)
            ->load();

        $regions = array(
            'config' => array(
                'show_all_regions' => $this->getShowNonRequiredState(),
                'regions_required' => $this->getCountriesWithStatesRequired()
            )
        );
        $excludeRegions = array('AE','AA');
        foreach ($collection as $region) {
            if (!$region->getRegionId()) {
                continue;
            }
            ***//Here is the code from the link given
             //BOF Custom Logic Here***
            $regionCode = $region->getCode();
            $this->_select->from(array('region'=>$this->_regionTable),
            array('region_id'=>'region_id', 'country_id'=>'country_id', 'code'=>'code', 'default_name'=>'default_name')
            )->where('code NOT IN (?)', $exclude_regions);

            //EOF Custom Logic Here
            $regions[$region->getCountryId()][$region->getRegionId()] = array(
                'code' => $region->getCode(),
                'name' => $this->__($region->getName())
            );
        }
        return $regions;
    }
```

After making the above changes, I tried below steps as my code is in **/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Helper/Data.php**

1. Create a module `Vids_Directory` in pool `local` like `app/code/local/Vids/Directory`
2. Create `app/etc/modules/Vids_Directory.xml`
3. Create `app/code/local/Vids/Directory/etc/config.xml`
4. create `app/code/local/Vids/Helper/Data.php`

Comment: You should add helper rewrite to your module config file

Comment: @veli I have already added that part in my config file.I have even registered my module in "Vids_Directory.xml" file